# How do I refresh a widget when the state of another class changes

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have a class `Avatar` that periodically changes it's attribute.
Whenever the attribute changes I want to update the Widget classes that are using
this attribute.

```
class Avatar {
  static int val = 0; 
  static void periodicTendencyValueChange() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 90), (timer) {
      val++; 
    });
  }
}

class Info1 extends StatefulWidget { 

  Info1({super.key });

  @override
  Info1Impl createState() => Info1Impl();
}

class Info1Impl extends State<Info1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text((Avatar.val).toString()); 
  }
}


class Info2 extends StatefulWidget { 

  Info2({super.key });

  @override
  Info2Impl createState() => Info2Impl();
}

class Info2Impl extends State<Info2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text((Avatar.val+1).toString); 
  }
}
```

What would be the most straight forward way of refreshing both Info Widgets - whenever the value in the class `Avatar` changes periodically?

Answer (score 0):

One simple and easy way to achieve this is by using the Provider package (which is also recommended as one of the state management techniques by the Flutter team: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Your Avatar class will extend Flutter's ChangeNotifier class. Anytime the value changes, it will notify any UI listeners.

Then you need to feed the Avatar class to the UI via the Provider package's ChangeNotifierProvider. The UI will automatically update anytime the Provider's values changes (important to set “listen” to true).

You will need to decide how far up the widget tree to place your Avatar ChangeNotifierProvider (it could even be placed inside the main.dart file if it must remain active app-wide all the time).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Avatar extends ChangeNotifier {
  int val = 0;

  void periodicTendencyValueChange() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 90), (timer) {
      val++;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}

class Info1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Info1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Avatar>(
        create: (context) => Avatar(),
        child: Text(Provider.of<Avatar>(context, listen: true).val.toString())
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all you need a timer breaking condition when you stop timer value increase.** 
**You must need to stop timer at a specific time/condition** 
for example I stop timer when `val == 10;`

```
 import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Avatar extends ChangeNotifier {

   int val = 0;
   int get value => val;

    periodicTendencyValueChange() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 90), (timer) {

      if(val<=9){
        val++;
        timer.cancel();
      }
      notifyListeners();

    });
  }
}
```

In every class you can implement like below

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
     
      create: (context) => Avatar(),
   
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Consumer<Avatar >(
              builder: (newContext, _Avatar, child) {
            _Avatar.periodicTendencyValueChange();
            return Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Text(_Avatar.value.toString())); // use this
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```